# Does Ros 2 work on any debian base distro or only ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, linux

How well does Ros 2 work on all debian based distros does it also have tier -1 support, or only ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best reference for supported platforms is [REP 2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html).

To directly answer your question, Debian platforms are not Tier 1 for any distribution at the moment. However because they are so closely tied to Ubuntu distributions they will generally work without any changes if you pick the closest analogous system. But you will have to compile from source.

Comment: Thanks for the share, all debian (debian 11) releases seem to be Tier 3 at the moment.